# Spring Integration CSV file to POJO transformer

Tags: spring-integration

I am facing some issues in getting the values from the payload in jdbc-outbound-adapter. The details are given below

a) Downloading csv files from remote server using int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter

b). Adding filename to the header using header-enricher

```
<int:transformer id="filetoPojoTransformer" input-channel="outputChannel" method="processContent"
          output-channel="fileOutputChannel" ref="FileToPOJOTransformer" />
```

c. Transforming the file content to POJO using custom transformer (used openCSV library to acheive this)

```
<int:transformer id="filetoPojoTransformer" input-channel="outputChannel" method="processContent"
          output-channel="fileOutputChannel" ref="FileToPOJOTransformer" />
```

d) FileToPOJOTransformer class below

```
public class FileToPOJOTransformer { 

    public List processContent(File file){   
            String[] columns = null;
            List<String> lines = null;
            List<Model1> list = null;

                try {
                    lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(), 
                            StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                columns = lines.get(0).split(",");              

                final ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<Model1> strategy = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<>();
                strategy.setType(Model1.class);
                strategy.setColumnMapping(columns);
                final CsvToBean<Model1> csvToBean = new CsvToBean<>();

                try (final Reader reader = new FileReader(file)) {
                    list = csvToBean.parse(strategy, reader);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                }
        return list;
        }

}
```

e) Using router delegating to corresponding channels based on the file name

```
<int:recipient-list-router id="customRouter" input-channel="fileOutputChannel" default-output-channel="nullChannel">
       <int:recipient channel="channel1" selector-expression="headers['fileName'].startsWith('File1')"/>
       <int:recipient channel="channel2" selector-expression="headers['fileName'].startsWith('File2')"/>       
     </int:recipient-list-router>
```

f) Now I have to store the content of CSV to database so I have used jdbc-outbound-adapter

```
<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter  
        id="jdbcOutBoundAdapterEndpoint1" channel="channel1"  
        query="insert into ImodiumTracking.ResponsesSent (Col1) 
        values(:payload.get(0).Col1)"
        data-source="dataSource">  
    </int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

I have tried different options to get the bean values but didn't work. How to obtain the bean values in the jdbc-outbound-adapter from the payload which contains list of POJOs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Show an expcetion
2. Show the content of your `List`
3. Why don't split that `List` to store each item to the DB?

Try this:

```
query="insert into ImodiumTracking.ResponsesSent (Col1) values(:payload[0].col1)"
```

if your POJO has `getCol1()`

Comment: Thanks Artem. Your solution works for one record but how do I insert all the records in the payload? do I need to use the split or is there any alternative solution? Please note that all the records in the csv are of similar type

Comment: Yes, you really should use `<splitter>` before `<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter>`. However I see that we can use `batchUpdate(String sql, SqlParameterSource[] batchArgs)` for such a case like yours. Feel free to raise a JIRA issue on the matter: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT

Comment: If I use <splitter> then there will be multiple calls to my database depending on the number of records and it might create performance issues

Comment: If you will do that within the same TX there won't be so big impact. From other side you can use `JdbcTemplate` directly from some custom `service-activator`. As I said: we don't support `batchUpdate` yet. That's why I asked you to create a JIRA ticket and we'll take care of it

Comment: Thanks Artem. I have checked the URL "jira.spring.io/browse/INT" but there is no link to create the ticket. Can you please advise?

Comment: Of course you should create an account. And if my answer is appropriate for you, please, accept it. Thanks for pointing this issue out.